# Finding lim of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Find $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty,y\to 0}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{x^2}{x+y}}$

My attempt:
$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{x^2}{x+y}}=e^{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{x^2}{x+y}}}$
So, we need calculate $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty, y\to 0}\frac{x^2}{x+y}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$. The only way to prove this limit $=1$ is using Squeeze theorem. But I don't know how to do it. Could anyone help me? Tks in advance.

Comment: You may use $${x^2\over x+y}\ln(1+{1\over x})={x\over x+y}\cdot x\ln(1+{1\over x})$$ The limit of the first factor is equal $1.$